Graph API - Deleting not working with username/password auth
Would love some help from any experts on this. I'm attempting to build a simple service that pulls emails from an Office 365 email box using the Microsoft Graph API. The service finds all new email, processes them using internal business logic, then deletes them from the box. Very standard service.
I've tried using both Application and Delegated authority and can't get it working either way. I can read the email, but deleting or moving it fails.
Dim graphClient As GraphServiceClient = Nothing
Dim scopes = {"Mail.ReadWrite"}
Dim options = New UsernamePasswordCredentialOptions With {.AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud}
Dim userNamePasswordCredential = New UsernamePasswordCredential(username:=username, password:=password, tenantId:=tenantId, clientId:=applicationId, options:=options)
graphClient = New GraphServiceClient(userNamePasswordCredential, scopes)
... Pull Emails... Now delete them:
Dim userReqHelper = graphClient.Me.Messages(messageId)
Await userReqHelper.DeleteAsync()
This throws an exception of "Content type text/html does not have a factory registered to be parsed"
I've tried deleting it with userReqHelper = graphClient.Users(userId).Messages(messageId).DeleteAsync() and userReqHelper = graphClient.Me.MailFolders(sourceFolder).Messages(messageId).DeleteAsync() with the same problem. I tried switching to using application client/secret authentication, but apparently delete doesn't support that. I tried interactive and it doesn't seem to work either, some kind of problem with the scope.
Application is registered with the tenant in Entra as an enterprise application with permissions and grants:

r/GraphAPI - Graph API - Deleting not working with username/password auth
I also enabled public client flows since some research showed that might help.

r/GraphAPI - Graph API - Deleting not working with username/password auth
Any suggestions appreciated!

Seems like an issue in the SDK. Do you use any official SDK for Graph API?

Just the Microsoft Graph package installed from NuGet

Your getting a HTML response to the delete request so the SDK can't handle that because it always expects a JSON response. You need to look at what's happening at the protocol layer eg use fiddler or the Graph Proxy and take a look at what the response actually is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-cloud/dev/dev-proxy/concepts/how-to-debug-microsoft-graph-calls
